# Python2.7 Zipfile problems

Tags: python

I have seen the other questions on this site, but none of them address this problem. Note I'm using Python 2.7. Structure is simplified for writing purposes.

Directory is as follows:

```
C:/Users/Tmp:
    mytest.jar
    sample.txt
```

Inside mytest.jar (opened with PKZIP):

```
com/
   random.class
META-INF/
```

Code is as follows:

```
import zipfile

def insertSample():
    with zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Users/Tmp/mytest.jar', "a") as jar:
        jar.write('C:/Users/Tmp/sample.txt', compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        jar.close()

def readjar():
    with zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Users/Tmp/mytest.jar', "r") as jar:
        jar.printdir()
        jar.close()
```

I'm trying to:

- read the contents in the JAR
- insert sample.txt into the JAR.

If I run readjar(), I get a weird error

```
"raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file".
```

If I run insertSample(), the code seems to pass, but then if I re-open the JAR file, it pops an error and everything is empty inside.

Also, due to compatibility issues, I have to use Python 2.7 :(

This is very odd, I have been following the solutions on the questions here exactly, so does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: By passing a second argument to `write()`, you're saying "I want `sample.txt` to be called `C:/Users/Tmp/mytest.jar` in this archive." I don't think that's what you want. (I'm not sure that's your problem, but it's probably _a_ problem.)

Comment: To add more to @glibdud's comment, try listing the *.jar* file contents (using *zipfile*), and when adding new elements to it, try to respect the existing pattern.

Comment: My goal was to run readjar() to list everything out first, but it looks likes the "r" argument in Zipfile is causing problems. Also edited to fix @glibdud comment